# ᚫᛄ•ᛟᛋᚱ•ᛗᚣᛚᚩᚻ•ᚩᚫ•ᚳᚦᚷᚹ•ᚹᛚᚫ•ᛉ

Tags: visual, cipher, computer-puzzle, alternate-reality-game

This is the rune page which has been found on-line in May 2014 released by the mysterious cyber group, Cicada 3301. It consists of cipher text which is the hint to the included hash.

[image: Page 56]

Transcript:

> ᚫᛄ•ᛟᛋᚱ•ᛗᚣᛚᚩᚻ•ᚩᚫ•ᚳᚦᚷᚹ•ᚹᛚᚫ•ᛉ ᚩᚪᛈ•ᛗᛞᛞᚢᚷᚹ•ᛚ•ᛞᚾᚣᛄ•ᚳᚠᛡ•ᚫᛏ ᛈᛇᚪᚦ•ᚳᚫ
>
> ```
> 36367763ab73783c7af284446c
> 59466b4cd653239a311cb7116
> d4618dee09a8425893dc7500b
> 464fdaf1672d7bef5e891c6e227
> 4568926a49fb4f45132c2a8b4
> ```
>
> ᚳᛞ•ᚠᚾ•ᛡᛖ•ᚠᚾᚳᛝ•ᚱF•ᚫᛁᚱᛞᛖ•ᛋᚣᛄᛠᚢ ᛝᚹ•ᛉᚩ•ᛗᛠᚹᚠ•ᚱᚷᛡ•ᛝᚱᛒ•ᚫᚾᚢᛋ•

Hint 1:

> ᚠᚢᚦᚩᚱ

Hint 2:

> 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23

Hint 3:

> Whirlpool

<sup>Credits & source: Page 56 of [Cicada 3301 puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicada_3301)</sup>

Comment: I think hints shouldn't be new puzzles.

Comment: Cicada hmmm, a lot is being heard about these...

Comment: Could we have a transcript? I don't want to spend a lot of time copying these down.

Comment: I guess a better title for this puzzle will spare you some downvote...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Cicada 3301 wiki](http://uncovering-cicada.wikia.com/wiki/File:56.jpg),

> shifting the runes by prime numbers

deciphers to

> AN END. WITHIN THE DEEP WEB THERE EXISTS A PAGE THAT HASHES TO: [hex string here]
> IT IS THE DUTY OF EUERY PILGRIM TO SEEK OUT THIS PAGE.

Comment: related: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3870/it-is-possible-to-find-a-tor-page-based-on-the-512-bit-hash

Comment: and this: https://www.reddit.com/r/cicada/comments/31l7lk/sorry_guys_there_is_no_tor_site_that_hashes_to/

Answer (score 4):

Partial Answer:

The text is

> writte in [Anglo-Saxon Runes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Saxon_runes)

The second hint refers to

> (some) prime numbers

Using this we get

> ae (ash)
>  j (year)
>  oe (ethel)
>  s (sun)
>  r (ride)
>  for the first few runes..
>  You could probably translate all the runes with the alphabet given on the wiki page but I'm running out of time to do so, so feel free to edit / suggest into this post at any given time!

Answer (score 0):

The text is not exactly as [@Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/37451/1854) posted.
The following Ruby source code found [here](http://codepad.org/qAfzIR96), computes the text to:

- > `AN END WItIN tE DEEP WEB tERE EXISTS A PAGE tAT HASHES TO IT IS tE DUTY OF EUERY PILGRIM TO SEEC OUT tIS PAGE`
- > `24 9 18 9 23 7 10 2 10 9 2 18 23 18 18 13 7 18 17 2 18 4 18 18 14 10 15 16 15 24 13 24 6 18 2 24 16 8 24 15 8 18 15 16 3 10 16 10 15 2 18 23 1 16 26 3 0 18 1 18 4 26 13 10 20 6 4 10 19 16 3 15 18 18 5 3 1 16 2 10 15 13 24 6 18`
- > `M oXOa tF Aa SIiJBW CYgHgS SH SESiMYRDiTiTG WYUuHo FEEN Ri RgNuCTM TWtSJae XU JUiUGP EFJ gTR`

You can [download it](http://codepad.org/qAfzIR96/raw.rb) and run it in the terminal as:

```
$ ruby raw.rb
```

However the hash code is still a mystery.

Comment: Just because he fixed some spelling? >.<

Comment: The "t"s are "TH". See the [gematria](http://cicada3301.org/gematria/), the first occurrence is **ᛚ** shifted back by $17-1=16$ yielding **ᚦ**, which is TH. The other spelling differences, every and seek, are there due to the lack of the letters v and k respectively.